# Creating new element on dynamicly created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So the question is, I get a json, from that json lenght I generate a list of devices with names and buttons next to them, the button has unique id name by device name, so the thing is, if I press button it has to open options window just for that device name so I can send it data to database for that device name, how do I create unique element for that dynamic button that every each button opens other options, without needing to create shit ton of divs with "display:none" because that just overloads page and slows it down. Tried doing with childElements, getting id and shit, but the same button press script doesnt open different options, I just cant get the head around it.

function a() {

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var dataFilt = new Array(4);
dataFilt[1] = "tenant=1";
dataFilt[2] = "tenant=2";
dataFilt[3] = "tenant=3";
dataFilt[4] = "option=all";

$.getJSON('"jsonIphere"?' + dataFilt[strUser]).done(function (devices) {
    // console.log(devices);
    $('.info').html('');
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    // for (i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    //
    //     $('.info').append('');
    // }


    //cycle to add as many divs as array of devices lenght is
    for (i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {

        $('.info').append('<div value="' + i + '" id="device'+ i +'" class="iconDescOpt col-md-12 paddingsToZero">\n' +
            '                    <!--=======================================icon picker===============================-->\n' +
            '                    <!--<button class="btn btn-default" data-placement="right" data-iconset="fontawesome" data-icon="fa-cog" role="iconpicker"></button>-->\n' +
            '                    \n' +
            '                    <div class="iconOnLeft col-md-2 paddingsToZero">\n' +
            '                        <div id="iconPicker' + i + ' "class="modal fade">\n' +
            '                            <div class="modal-dialog">\n' +
            '                                <div class="modal-content">\n' +
            '                                    <div class="modal-header">\n' +
            '                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\n' +
            '                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Icon Picker</h4>\n' +
            '                                    </div>\n' +
            '                                    <div class="modal-body">\n' +
            '                                        <div>\n' +
            '                                            <ul class="icon-picker-list">\n' +
            '                                                <li>\n' +
            '                                                    <a data-class="{{item}} {{activeState}}" data-index="{{index}}"><span class="{{item}}"></span><span class="name-class">{{item}}</span>\n' +
            '                                                    </a>\n' +
            '                                                </li>\n' +
            '                                            </ul>\n' +
            '                                        </div>\n' +
            '                                    </div>\n' +
            '                                    <div class="modal-footer">\n' +
            '                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel\n' +
            '                                        </button>\n' +
            '                                    </div>\n' +
            '                                </div>\n' +
            '                            </div>\n' +
            '                        </div>\n' +
            '                        <button class="btn iconButton" data-placement="right" data-iconset="fontawesome"\n' +
            '                                data-icon="fa-cog" role="iconpicker">\n' +
            '                        </button>\n' +
            '                        <!--===============================icon picker end================================-->\n' +
            '                    </div>\n' +
            '                    <div class="descriptionDevice col-md-8 paddingsToZero">\n' +
            '                        <p>' + devices[i].name + '</p>\n' +
            '                    </div>\n' +
            '                    <div class="optButton col-md-2">\n' +
            '                        <button class="btn iconButton" id="'+ devices[i].name +'">\n' +
            '                            <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true">\n' +
            '                            </i>\n' +
            '                        </button>\n' +
            '                    </div>\n' +
            '\n' +
            '                </div>');
        // $('#optionsHere').append('<div id="itemToHide" class="optionsOfDevice col-md-12 paddingsToZero" style="display: none">\n' +
        //     '                <div class="deleteAndAdd info paddingsToZero">\n' +
        //     '\n' +
        //     '                </div>\n' +
        //     '                <div class="deleteAndAdd info paddingsToZero">\n' +
        //     '\n' +
        //     '                </div>\n' +
        //     '            </div>'
        // );

    }


});
```

}

a();

so this code gets json, and creates as much elements with cycle as there is array objects inside with those object names inside, the commented part is that creates option window with display none for each device name

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Verifiable Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code to get meaningful answers.

Comment: Longest sentence in history of mankind.. What did you try so far?

Comment: Tried creating "display:none" divs next to the devices list, but the page load goes from 1ms to 5min, couse there is list of 200 devices and it needs to create shit ton of option pages and in that option page are more options that can be pressed, so you get the idea.

I am not good of expressing my self.

Comment: Edited, added code snipet